# Uncaught TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.collections is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collections("todos").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setTodos(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().todob));
    });
  }, []);
```

I keep getting this error when trying to connect my firebase to my react App

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try db.collection. I think there is a typo there